# jupyter enviroment has different libraries available to ssh session even though using same python

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter-lab

When i SSH into the linux machine and open a python prompt and for example, import a library" it says “ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘Adafruit_MotorHAT’”

```
jetbot@nano-4gb-jp45:~$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type “help”, “copyright”, “credits” or “license” for more information.

from Adafruit_MotorHAT import Adafruit_MotorHAT, Adafruit_DCMotor
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “”, line 1, in
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘Adafruit_MotorHAT’
```

However, when i run the same command in jupyter which is running the same python it imports fine. Why is the ssh python session not importing the libraries, what am i missing?

Here’s the python information from jupyter

[image: python information from jupyter]

Heres the same information from the ssh python session :

jetbot@nano-4gb-jp45:/bin$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type “help”, “copyright”, “credits” or “license” for more information.

import sys
print(sys.path)
[’’, ‘/usr/lib/python36.zip’, ‘/usr/lib/python3.6’, ‘/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload’, ‘/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages’, ‘/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages’, ‘/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages’]

Comment: This could be that the Adafruit_MotorHAT package was installed via conda instead of pip and available only in a Conda environment

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  How do i know this? is there a command that will tell me?

Comment: You can check it in anaconda navigator, environments. you will see the list of packages or you can search for a particular one. Next to the package name, under column Type there will be an icon (python or anaconda), and if you mouse-over it, will show the type (python or conda)

Comment: something weird is going off.  I cant run conda (cant find it), i cant see jupyter in "apt list".   Any thoughts?  I'm using a pre-created image from jetson nano (nvidia) and trying to work out how its setup.  They have got all the libraries working with this image of linux for their hardware and people struggle when moving away to get everything setup.